# Analysis limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The function
$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}$
is defined at every point of the interval $(0,\infty)$ except for the point 2. By applying the the fact that if I is an interval and c is a point of I, where f1 is a function defined and continuous on I, and f2 is defined everywhere on I except possibly c. Let $f1(x) = f2(x)$ for $x$ not equal to $c$, then the limit of f2 as x approaches c exists and equals f2(c). Prove that the limit as x approaches 2 f(x) exists, and find its value. 
Will need this result:
if g is a function that is defined and continuous on an interval I and never takes the value 0 and f is another function that is defined and continuous on I, then f/g is continuous
(You may NOT use l'H^opital's Rule
since we have not proved it or even defined derivatives yet. Furthermore, such
an approach would be circular since the calculation involved in this problem is
similar to the ones that will be needed to justify derivative calculations later in
the course.)

Im not sure where to start on this problem, guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I started it off for you. Regards

Comment: Guidance? Read your lecture notes.

(This site is not populated by homework gnomes that live to do people's homework for them!)

Comment: Nowhere did I ask for anyone to do my homework for me, I just asked for a tip to help me begin working on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $$x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$$ and $$x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2).$$ This should let you use the given fact.